why don't Show EF Core 6, AppDbContext onModelCreating in modelbuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Schema name");

why dont Show EF Core 6, AppDbContext  onModelCreating in
modelbuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Schema name");


i tried different methods,
I almost asked the AIs too,
ChatGPT, Bing etc. but somehow I don't like it.
Answer the sixth question before blocking


I'm read another docs and question in stackoverflow, reddit, medium
google etc,

As for the expected result
it just won't get called, I tried adding all kinds of namespaces but it didn't work.

Just to make sure : what is the version of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore nuget package you installed? I've got pretty much the same usings / code as you do and having no issues, I'm thinking you might be on an old version.

my package version Ef-Core 6.01

I'm fixing this error

I'm fixing It.

EF-Core Relational dont installed before but now I'm installed Relational then fix this error

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

I'm fixing It.

EF-Core Relational dont installed before but now I'm installed Relational then fix this error
